# How to Lower Volume Of Auto Play Of html Video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I add the video in the header, which will play automatically after loading page, but I'm unable to lower the volume of the video..

I tried using some Javascript to control the volume but it's not working...

```
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.01;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What's that `}` for?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console (hit F12). Your code has a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place your script before the closing `</body>` tag.
That will make sure that JS read all the elements in your page before being able to manipulate them.

```
<script >
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  vid.volume = 0.01;
</script>

</body>
```

Example:

```html
<body>

<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="360" controls="" autoplay="">
 <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!-- Safari / iOS, IE9 -->
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm"><!-- Chrome10+, Ffx4+, Opera10.6+ -->
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg"><!-- Firefox3.6+ / Opera 10.5+ -->
</video>
  
  
<script >
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  vid.volume = 0.1;
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: @ImranIqbal it *will* work if you remove the extra `}`

Comment: yes now it's working.. Breacket Was Wrongly Placed And I Didn't Notice About It..thanks

Comment: Can You Also Help Me To Stop Video When User Will Scroll Down?

Comment: here is question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750790/how-stop-auto-play-while-scroll-down

Comment: @ImranIqbal Google, search, play, try something! Start searching: "how to get window scroll position in JS".