# How Stop Auto Play While Scroll Down

Tags: javascript, html, video

I Add Video In Header Which Played Automatically But I'm Unable To Stop Video When User Scroll Down To Page..

Comment: You need to show some code of what you tried.

Comment: Are you using HTML5 video, or a service like youtube, vimeo, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Google youtube API for this purpose.

```js
 // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
   
   // Youtuber API
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '315',
          width: '560',
    playerVars : {
                autoplay : 0,
                controls: 0,
                disablekb:0,
                modestbranding:1,
                showinfo:0

            },
          videoId: '3MGrgzTGdtE',
          events: {
     
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
  player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
          height: '315',
          width: '560',
    playerVars : {
                autoplay : 0
            },
          videoId: '3MGrgzTGdtE',
          events: {
     
            //'onReady': onPlayerReady2,
            //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
          event.target.mute();
        //event.target.playVideo();
      }
    
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
   
    $(window).scroll(function() {
     var topOfOthnxtDiv = $("#parelaxhome").offset().top;  
        $("#medicinediv").each( function() {
            if( ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top)   ) {
               // $(this).css('opacity',1);
                player.playVideo();
            } if($(window).scrollTop() >= topOfOthnxtDiv)  {
                //$(this).css('opacity',0);
                player.stopVideo();
            }
        }); 
    });
 
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.pclose').click(function(){
   player2.stopVideo();
  })
  $('.clickpop').click(function(){
   player2.playVideo();
            player2.seekTo(0);
   player2.unMute();
  })
    });
```

```html
<div class="videodiv">
    <div id="myframe">
    <div id="play-video"></div>
    <div id="player"></div>
 </div>
```